# Compactly Supported Function's Inductive Limit Topology is Independent of Inductive System

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\{C_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interiors.  Define the inductive limit topology on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^m)$ using the inductive system $(C_n,i_{n,m})$ where $i_{n,m}$ is the obvious inclusion map.

Why is the topology on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^m)$ independent of the $C_n$?

Comment: "Unductive" in the title. Could be worse: Someone on this site mis-spelled "Probability" as "Boopability" in a title,  so I looked up the word "boop". :)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  That's hilarious.  Does it mean anything?

Comment: Boop: To affectionately poke someone's nose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by instead thinking of the directed system $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$, which consists of *all* compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ partially ordered by inclusion. Then, you can define the direct limit topology exactly as you did. In this case, the direct limit *is* $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The question is, why does your $\{C_n\}$ of increasing compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that in the limit covers $\mathbb{R}^n$ I assume, else this does not hold), also yield the same direct limit? It's because the $\{C_n\}$ is *cofinal* in $\{C_i\}$ i.e. for any element $a \in \{C_i\}$, there is an element $b \in \{C_n\}$ such that $a \leq b$.

It is a fact (whose proof you can look up) that the direct limit over a cofinal subset is isomorphic to the direct limit over the entire directed set. This is why the choice of the cofinal subset does not matter.

Edit: You can find a proof of my claim in the last $2$ pages here http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/Notes/06_categories.pdf

Comment: Interesting.  From a conceptual standpoint.  What does it mean to converge in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: I’m honestly not familiar at all with the topology on $C_c(K)$ with $K$ compact. I feel like this is the topology of uniform convergence (you can correct me otherwise). Regardless, given a sequence of functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R^n})$, there is probably a way (that I can’t think of right now) to find some compact $K$ so that the supports of all the $f_n$ lie in $K$. Thus convergence in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ boils down to convergence in $C_c(K)$.

Comment: This is sort of the essence of direct limits. In fact the reason why the direct limit of the cofinal and overall system agree is precisely because any elements I want to work with, I could find somewhere in the cofinal subset to work with them (in a very handwavey sort of sense).

Comment: This is very interesting.  Do you happen to have a reference, besdies the notes, that does in more detail.  Like a book with a descent chapter/section on this sort of thing?

Comment: I actually had a hard time finding references for this statement (and was able to find MSE answers about inverse limits instead of direct ones). Eventually I found one in _Categories for the Working Mathematician_ but it's well into abstract nonsense. It uses the concept of _final categories_ (which generalize cofinal subsets), but does prove the statement in generality. In particular, chapter IX (Special Limits) section 3 (Final Functors) has the statement and proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334523/bijection-between-direct-limits Actually I just found this here that's way more tractable.

Comment: Just one thing, what does $a\leq b$ mean in this case?

Comment: You mean $i\leq n$ in the poset I?

Comment: $i$ and $n$ are indices from two different index sets so you can’t really compare them. If you compare $a$ and $b$ in $I$, then $a \leq b$ i.e. $a$ includes into $b$. If you look at this as a poset category, than there is a morphism $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Sorry I got confused for a second because I thought a and b were functions.  But yes, in this case all is clear :)